# Crontab append a command to certain user using shell

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job using a shell script but I am unable to find a solution to it I am trying to use crontab like this:

```
#cron.sh
echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab -
```

I can run cron.sh as a sudo user So my question is how to add this cron job to a specific user I am using this command:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c  "echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab -" -g user user
```

but it doesn't work how to make the above code work.

Comment: Why do you want to do it via `echo` and not with `crontab -e`?

Comment: I am using some shell script to create a cronjob and that script run as a sudo. And I don't know how to run crontab -e from a shell script and assign to a specific user.

Comment: So the reason why you use a script is because you want to setup the crontab for a bunch of users simultaneously? Perhaps we have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here? What happens if you later find that you want to **modify** the crontab entry for all of them? If you are going to write a script for automatic editing, it becomes a nightmare. IMO each user should be responsible for his own crontab. I would get pretty upset if someone changes mine under the hood....

Comment: Also, in your code, `crontab` is not executed via `su`. Only the `bash -c echo` is.

Comment: I am new to shell scripting and I want to be able to append */1**** /opt/file/test.sh this to my corn job for one specific user. Do you know how to append it using shell script

Comment: I can't give you an authoritative answer, since I never done this from a script, but my attempt would be to run the complete command under `su`, i.e. `su -s "echo ... | crontab ...`. Executing just the `echo` as superuser is pointless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info may be of some help. Good luck.